# Why is the bridge rectifier circuit widely used to make power supplies?

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance

Why is the  bridge rectifier circuit widely used to make power supplies? Which is better - a  bridge rectifier with capacitor or without capacitor?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I could swear I edited an almost exaclty worded duplicate of this question in the last few days.  Can't find it now.

Comment: @JRE Yes. Apparently closed, deleted, asked again *there* and migrated...

Comment: Whether you need a capacitor or not depends.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is the bridge rectifier circuit widely used to make power supplies?

Because it's an effective way to convert AC into DC.  Many types of power supply are supplied with AC and need to produce DC.

> Which is better - a bridge rectifier with capacitor or without capacitor?

In most cases, you need a capacitor to convert the very ripply DC from the bridge rectifier into something smoother.

Answer (score 2):

I have a light dimmer that uses a single diode to output (½) of each AC cycle. A bridge rectifier will output both halves with the same polarity.  If you want a relatively smooth DC output, you need a capacitor to store charge when the output voltage is high and then give it back when the voltage tries to drop.  For that, a half wave output require a much bigger capacitor. Many modern DC power supplies rectify the high voltage input and use that to drive a high frequency oscillator. Both the step-down transformer and the final filter capacitor can be much smaller and lighter when functioning at a high frequency.